# How to create a generic extension method?

Tags: c#, generics

I want to develop a Generic Extension Method which should arrange the string in alphabetical then by lengthwise ascending order.

I mean

```
string[] names = { "Jon", "Marc", "Joel",
                  "Thomas", "Copsey","Konrad","Andrew","Brian","Bill"};

var query = names.OrderBy(a => a.Length).ThenBy(a => a);
```

What is the way to develop Generic Extension Method?

I tried :

```
public static class ExtensionOperation
    {
        public static T[] AlphaLengthWise<T>(this T[] names)
        {
            var query = names.OrderBy(a => a.Length).ThenBy(a => a);
            return query;
        }
    }
```

I received :

> Error 1: T does not contain definition for Length
>
> Error 2: can not convert `System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable` to `T[]`.

Comment: Having a generic method that only works on strings doesn't really make a whole lot of sense...

Comment: Why it should be generic if you want to arrange strings only?

Comment: @bniwredyc Because `generic` sounds cool! :)

Comment: You may want to also correct `ExtensionOperstion` to `ExtensionOperation`

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The first error is because `Length` is a property of the `String` class while in your generic version the type of the T parameter is not known. It could be any type.

The second error is because you return just the query object but not the actual result. You might need to call `ToArray()` before returning.

With little modifications you could come up with this:

```
public static class ExtensionOperation
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> AlphaLengthWise<T, L>(
        this IEnumerable<T> names, Func<T, L> lengthProvider)
    {
        return names
            .OrderBy(a => lengthProvider(a))
            .ThenBy(a => a);
    }
}
```

Which you could use like this:

```
string[] names = { "Jon", "Marc", "Joel", "Thomas", "Copsey", "Konrad", "Andrew", "Brian", "Bill" };
var result = names.AlphaLengthWise(a => a.Length);
```

Comment: I find myself using techniques like this `lengthProvider` a lot with generic code.  It's just one more reason I love lambdas so much.  :D

Answer (score 13):

Why do you want to do this generically? Just use

```
public static class ExtensionOperations
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> AlphaLengthWise(this string[] names)
    {
        var query = names.OrderBy(a => a.Length).ThenBy(a => a);
        return query;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `string[]` and not `IEnumerable<String>`? You could remove the `.ToArray()` and leave it deferred (if I am not mistaken).

Comment: This ignores the question and presents a solution to a completely different problem

Answer (score 9):

I think you may be a little confused to the purpose of generics.

Generics are a way to tailor a class or method to a specific type. A generic method or class is designed to work for *any* type. This is most easily illustrated in the `List<T>` class, where it can be tailored to be a list of any type. This gives you the type-safety of knowing the list only contains that specific type.

Your problem is designed to work on a specific type, the `string` type. Generics are not going to solve a problem which involves a specific type.

What you want is a simple (non-generic) Extension Method:

```
public static class ExtensionOperations
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> AlphaLengthWise(
        this IEnumerable<string> names)
    {
        if(names == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("names");

        return names.OrderBy(a => a.Length).ThenBy(a => a);
    }
}
```

Making the argument and the return type `IEnumerable<string>` makes this a non-generic extension method which can apply to any type implementing `IEnumerable<string>`. This will include `string[]`, `List<string>`, `ICollection<string>`, `IQueryable<string>` and many more.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to develop a Generic Extension Method which should arrange **the strings** in alphabetical then ...

```
public static class ExtensionOperation
{
    public static IEnumerable<String> AplhaLengthWise(
                                   this IEnumerable<String> names)
    {
        return names.OrderBy(a => a.Length).ThenBy(a => a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy how Microsoft does it:

```
public static class ExtensionOperation {
    // Handles anything queryable.
    public static IOrderedQueryable<string> AlphaLengthWise(this IQueryable<string> names) {
        return names.OrderBy(a => a.Length).ThenBy(a => a);
    }
    // Fallback method for non-queryable collections.
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<string> AlphaLengthWise(this IEnumerable<string> names) {
        return names.OrderBy(a => a.Length).ThenBy(a => a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `T[]`. Other than that, you won't be able to use `Length` of `T`, since not all types has a `Length` property. You could modify your extension method to `.OrderBy(a => a.ToString().Length)`

If you know you'll always be dealing with strings, use `IEnumerable<String>` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`, and you'll be able to access the `Length` property immediately.

Comment: Changing T[] to IEnumerable<T> won't demand Length property for elements.

Comment: it sure won't. that part of the answer was with regards to the second error. `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so that would solve that part of the problem. As for the `Length` property, my suggestion was that `ToString()` was used to ensure a string, or, if he new he'd always be dealing with strings, to change `T` to `string`.