# Possible to declare an interface containing an extension?

Tags: c#, interface, extension-methods

As part of a testing library, I would like to define an interface which says 'this object knows how to initialize itself randomly'. If members of the randomly filled object are references, the random initialization should be capable of assigning `null` to these members.

If I was doing this for one class, the code could look like this

```
public class QWorker
{
    double mxVal = 0;

    public void fillRandomly(System.Random xRng)
    {
        mxVal = xRng.NextDouble();
    }
}

public class QBoss
{
    public QWorker mxWorker;

    void fillRandomly(System.Random xRng)
    {
        if (xRng.Next() % 2 == 1)
            x1 = null;
        else
        {
            x1 = new QWorker();
            x1.fillRandomly(xRng);
        }
    }    
}
```

Now if `QBoss` had mulitple reference-type members, if/else would have to be done for every member. It would look ugly and could be cumbersome to maintain. To cimrcumvent, I came up with the following sample code:

```
public interface QIRandomizable<T> where T : new()
{
    static void fillRandomly(this System.Random xThis, ref T xRef); // XXX
}

class QWorker : QIRandomizable<QWorker>
{
    public double mxDouble;
}

public static class QWorkerExtensions 
{
    public static void fillRandomly(this System.Random xThis, ref QWorker xRef)
    {
        if ((xThis.Next() % 2) == 1)
            xRef = null;
        else
        {
            xRef = new QWorker();
            xRef.mxDouble = xThis.NextDouble();
        }
    }
}

public class QBoss : QIRandomizable<QBoss>
{
    public QWorker mx1;
    public QWorker mx2;

    public static void fillRandomly(this System.Random xThis, ref QBoss xRef)
    {
        xRef = new QBoss();
        xThis.fillRandomly(ref xRef.mxMember1);    // can be null
        xThis.fillRandomly(ref xRef.mxMember2);    // can be null
    }
}
```

However this does not compile and the first problem is on line marked XXX - the static keyword does not belong there.

As a result, I would like to ask the following:

1. Is it possible to declare an interface with an extension inside?
2. If yes, what should I change?
3. If not, is there a different way how to accomplish what I want?

Any help is much appreciated, 
Daniel

Comment: Is this what you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825952/how-to-create-a-generic-extension-method

Comment: @PaulF: Im sorry bu I cant see the resemblance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, you cannot. That's because you can only declare instance-methods on an interface, and extension methods must be static.

You can try something like this:

```
public interface IDoesSomething
{
    void fillRandomly(Random r);
}
public class QBoss
{
    public double mx1 { get; set; }
    public double mx2 { get; set; }
    public int mx3 { get; set; }

    public object refType { get; set; }

    public void fillRandomly(Random r)
    {
        FillRandom(GetProps(this), this, r);    
    }
}


public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetProps(object blah)
{
    return blah.GetType().GetProperties();
}

public static void FillRandom(IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> obj, object onObj, Random r)
{
    Action<PropertyInfo, object> setVal = (prop, val) => { prop.SetValue(onObj, val); };
    foreach (var o in obj)
    {
        if (!o.PropertyType.IsValueType)
        {
            if (r.Next() % 2 != 1)
            {
                var v = Activator.CreateInstance(o.PropertyType);
                setVal(o, v);
                var id = v as IDoesSomething;
                if (id != null)
                    id.fillRandomly(r);
            }
        }
        if (o.PropertyType == typeof(double))
            setVal(o, r.NextDouble());
        if (o.PropertyType == typeof(int))
            setVal(o, (int)(r.NextDouble() * 100));

        //etc, etc
    }
}
```

Here, you decide what to do *once*, and set the properties. This currently only works for properties, not fields, so you might want to refactor it a little to take both `FieldInfo` and `PropertyInfo`

Testing it yields:

> mx1    0.786868741170908
>   mx2     0.434705327001729
>   mx3     51
>   refType Object

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is way beyond my current level of C# knowledge and I have deadline. However, I will favorite this to learn new stuff later.